# Installshield in VS2012 and deployment of web application in IIS7.5

Tags: iis7, asp.net-mvc, deployment

I deployed a web application in IIS 7.5 using *installshield*. But after deploying the site I am facing below error on accessing the site from URL.

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
```

Possible causes: A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.

I also specified default document as one of `.cshtml` file in my project and make directory browsing enable. But still I am facing same error.